# How to convert this complex Entity Framework query into a standard SQL query? What exactly perform?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have no experience with .NET **Entity Framework** and I have to understand what exactly do this Entitity Framework query and translate in in classic SQL (for Microsoft SQL server)

So I have this query:

```
using (MyCorp.EarlyWarnings.Model.EarlyWarningsEntities context = new Model.EarlyWarningsEntities())
            {
                DBContext.SetTimeout(context);
float vulnerabilities_thisweek = (from x in context.VulnerabilityAlertDocuments
                                .Select(p => new { p.Id, p.Published, p.Title, p.Severity, p.LastUpdated })
                                .AsEnumerable()
                                .Select(p => new MyCorp.EarlyWarnings.Model.VulnerabilityAlertDocument()
                                {
                                    Id = p.Id,
                                    Published = p.Published,
                                    Title = p.Title,
                                    Severity = p.Severity,
                                    LastUpdated = p.LastUpdated
                                })
                                .Where(p => p.LastUpdated.Date > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7).Date)
                                                  select x).Count();
}
```

I know that the result of this query on my database is **-1,00** (I know this information executing this query)

I also know that this query work on a single table (or at least I think it is so, correct if I am saying wrong thing) because I have **from x in context.VulnerabilityAlertDocuments** and in the **EarlyWarningsEntities** class I found this property that map the Data Base table named as **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** on the **DbSet** object named **VulnerabilityAlertDocuments**:

```
public DbSet<VulnerabilityAlertDocument> VulnerabilityAlertDocuments { get; set; }
```

So I think that my SQL query have to work only on the **VulnerabilityAlertDocument** database table.

I can't understand what exactly do when in the **where** condition use the **=>** "operator", I have try to search on Google but I can't find nothing

I also have some difficulties to understand what exactly do the **AsEnumerable()** method called on the .Select() result.

Reading the documentation it seems to me that the first .Select() method return to me a set of rows and then it is called the **AsEnumerable()** method to have an iterator on this collection but I am not sure, do you confirm or is it wrong?

Then it execute a second select and I can't understand on what (it seems to me that the table is the same)

Someone can help me to understand what exactly do this query and how can I convert it in standard SQL?

Tnx

Answer (score 1):

Your query is creating an anonimous type just for nothing, i have not tested but i think something like the following will produce the same results:

```
float vulnerabilities_thisweek = (from x in context.VulnerabilityAlertDocuments                                    
                                 .Where(p => p.LastUpdated > DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7))
                                 .Count();
}
```

also i recomend you to take a look to [LinqPad](https://www.linqpad.net/), you can test your linq queries and see the corresponding sql statements

Comment: are you saying to me that LinkPad can show me the SQL query converion of the Entity framework query?

Comment: Exactly, it is very easy to setup, i recommend you to download the portable version.

Comment: O, I have downloaded it but now what have I to do to translate my Entity framework query to SQL query using LinkPad? Have I first to create a DB connection? and then?

Comment: Just execute the query, in the bottom panel you can switch between Result pane, Sql Lamdda and IL. Put the code i post you and see what you get. You have to select "c# Statements" in this case.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be overly complicated for a COUNT query..

From what I see, this can translate into:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM VulnerabilityAlertDocuments WHERE DateDiff(day, LastUpdated,  GetDate()) < 8
```

Comment: mmm can you explain to me what exactly do my query and how you convert it into your version?

Comment: apologies, had to step away from my desk. In regards to how I converted it, I walked backwards. .Count & the .Where. Everything above those is extraneous. As far as what your query is doing, it is selecting certain fields, creating an anonymous type, then recreating `VulnerabilityAlertDocument` with only the selected fields from the anonymous type, then applying the Where function and then counting it. Most of it is not needed.